Tinymce fontsizeinput default value
Look at: https://codepen.io/pennan88/pen/zYXRdbO

Use TinyMCE 7.0.0
Create a minimal Editor using toolbar = 'fontsizeinput'
Define, even it is regarding to the documentation the default, font_size_input_default_unit:'pt'.


Problem
When setting font_size_input_default_unit: "pt" even if it's the default value, the input-box still displays px. So if i set the font-size to 11 pt, it gets displayed as 14.6667px.

Expected result
I'd expect the input-box to display the unit Npt, where N is any number.

Tested on

Browser: Edge, latest version
OS: Windows 11
TinyMCE version: 7.0.0 and 6.8.1
Environment:

Local computer, running Blazor WASM
NET7.0
TinyMCE.Blazor with <script src="_content/TinyMCE.Blazor/tinymce-blazor.js"></script> or
TinyMCE.Blazor and TinyMCE which downloads a local lib with the files



